# htaccess rename address bar

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is the deal, when the user types www.so360.com.br, I want the user to be redirected to /www/so360/ folder on the server, like if it was www.so360.com.br/so360/index.html. BUT... I want the user to see this in the address bar:

www.so360.com.br/

Simply put: User types www.so360.com.br - User sees on address bar www.so360.com.br - User sees a webpage from www.so360.com.br/so360/index.html

HOW? By the way, www.astumobilis.com points to the same host, which I don't think it will interfere.

Here is my htaccess: Mod rewrite is ON.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?astumobilis\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www\.so360\.com\.br/so360/index\.html [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this right above the `</IfModule>`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} so360\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /so360/index.html [L]
```

This won't cause the browser to redirect so the URL in the location bar won't change (unless `index.html` redirects the browser to something).

To route everything else, add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} so360\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!so360/)(.+)$ /so360/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! but... I would like to be automatic like, when I create a folder in the server under /www/so360/ like this:

www.so360.com.br/ap1/

but what happens is, when I create a folder, it shows this on the address bar:

www.so360.com.br/so360/ap1/
how to solve this?

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thanks Jon Lin! o/
Do you have any documents so I can learn more about htaccess? Would like to understand :)